# How to set exact chart area size in excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I know how to set the size of the diagram, but I cannot find the option for setting the size of the `chart area` (not sure if this is the correct name in English). The box I want to change is marked with a red arrow in the figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With VBA, assuming you set:

```
Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
```

Then you can use:

```
myChart.Chart.PlotArea.Height = desired width
```

or:

```
myChart.Chart.PlotArea.Width = desired height
```

If you want to enlarge the plot area to a value greater than the current chart area, you will need to enlarge the latter first, using:

```
myChart.Chart.ChartArea.Height = desired height
myChart.Chart.ChartArea.Width = desired width
```

Comment: That;s the plot area, but the rectangle is really the plot "inside" area, and the plot area includes a margin that has room for axis labels etc. You can change the plot area in code, not the plot inside area, so you need to do a little algebra in your code to make it work out.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest (non-VBA) way I know to do this is:

1. Build your chart
2. Select `Page Layout` from `View` > `Workbook Views`.  This will let you set your dimensions in "real" units (e.g. inches, mm).
3. Adjust your column width and row height to the required size.
4. Select `Snap to Grid` from `Page Layout` > `Arrange` > `Align`
5. Arrange your chart so that the `Chart Area` snaps to a cell of the required dimensions.

Comment: Nice workaround!